# How to orient primitives faced to camera?

Tags: opengl, 3d, glsl

I am developing 3D engine using "modern" OpenGL with shaders. I faced with a problem which I have no ideas how to solve.

I am trying to make primitives that are drawn to be faced to screen. Actually, I am talking about arrows. My inputs are starting point and direction of arrow.

I have some software which can perform this and I'd like to reproduce such behavior.

Mention, that arrows are always oriented to screen whatever I rotate model.

[image]
[image]

Also, they are re-sizing accordingly to scaling of model.

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

As ***Moby Disk*** suggested I tried to follow his steps. But after applying following code still cannot get desirable result. Please, consider my code:

```
    var arrowStart = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

    var arrowLength = 1f;
    var widthOfArrowHead  = 0.1f;

    var viewMatrix = Matrix4.LookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, 1), new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 1, 0));
    var projectionMatrix = Matrix4.CreateOrthographic(ViewportSize.Width, ViewportSize.Height, NearZPlane, FarZPlane);
    var modelMatrix = Matrix4.CreateRotationY(XRotation) * Matrix4.CreateRotationX(YRotation) * Matrix4.CreateRotationZ(0);

    Vector3 cameraRight = new Vector3(viewMatrix[0, 0], viewMatrix[1, 0], viewMatrix[2, 0]);
    Vector3 cameraUp = new Vector3(viewMatrix[0, 1], viewMatrix[1, 1], viewMatrix[2, 1]);

    Vector3 arrowDirection = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
    Vector3 arrowEnd = new Vector3(arrowStart.X + arrowDirection.X * arrowLength, arrowStart.Y + arrowDirection.Y * arrowLength, arrowStart.Z + arrowDirection.Z * arrowLength);

    arrowStart = Vector3.TransformPosition(arrowStart, viewMatrix * modelMatrix * projectionMatrix);
    arrowEnd = Vector3.TransformPosition(arrowEnd, viewMatrix * modelMatrix * projectionMatrix);

    var arrowHeadPoint = Vector3.One;

    arrowHeadPoint = 0.9f * arrowLength * cameraUp + widthOfArrowHead * cameraRight;
    var oneArrowHeadPoint4 = Vector4.Transform(new Vector4(arrowHeadPoint, 1.0f), viewMatrix * projectionMatrix);
```

Can someone help me to make this done?

Comment: Look up the term "billboarding."  Basically, you use the camera's up vector.

Comment: @Moby Disk can you provide full answer? I got the idea of billboarding when textures are in use, but how to apply it for my solution - no idea. :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not really qualified to answer this since my OpenGL knowledge is vastly out-of-date!  Hopefully math has not changed though. :-)  Conceptually, if you know the starting point of the arrow in world space, you can calculate an ending point that is above it like this:

```
CreateUpArrow(Point startOfArrow, Matrix viewMatrix)
{
   const lengthOfArrow = 10
   Vector cameraUp_worldspace = {viewMatrix[0][1], viewMatrix[1][1], viewMatrix[2][1]}
   Point endOfArrow = cameraUp_worldspace * lengthOfarrow
   // So endOfArrow is now 10 world units above the startOfArrow, where "above" is "toward the top of the screen"
   // Now you have two points you can use to draw an arrow
   // You can do something similar to create the arrowhead too
}
```

This is similar to "billboarding" in that you want to calculate points, in 3D space, that align to the camera.  With a billboard, you know the center of the billboard, and you calculate 4 points that form a quad.  In this case though, maybe you are drawing lines so you want the start of the arrow, the end of the arrow, and some points to form the arrowhead.

Another approach would be to draw a billboard with an arrow texture on it.

I stole the formula above from this article on billboarding http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/billboards-particles/billboards/ it states:

> In camera space, the camera’s up vector is (0,1,0). To get it in world
> space, just multiply this by the matrix that goes from Camera Space to
> World Space, which is, of course, the inverse of the View matrix.
>
> CameraRight_worldspace = {ViewMatrix[0][0], ViewMatrix[1][0], ViewMatrix[2][0]}
>
> CameraUp_worldspace = {ViewMatrix[0][1], ViewMatrix[1][1], ViewMatrix[2][1]}

So you can expand on my pseudo-code to calculate the other points on the arrowhead.  The rightmost point of the arrowhead might be at (0.9 * lengthOfArrow * cameraUp_worldspace + widthOfArrowHead * cameraRight_worldspace) to get a point that is 90% of the arrow length and a little bit off to the right.  Do the same for the left, to get 4 points to make an arrow.

I hope this helps!